# What is best way to implement fine grained access control in struts2 view?

Tags: struts2, access-control

Basically, In any application for UI we have access control for various element.

Say, I have a button to be visible to PM

```
<logic equal=pm>
TheButton
</logic equal>

<logic NotEqual=pm>
TheButton=disabled
</logic NotEqual>
```

Now say there is one more condition say developer has different access. 
Since there is no AND in tags...We do as

```
<logic equal=pm>
TheButton
</logic equal>

<logic NotEqual=pm>
TheButton=disabled
</logic NotEqual>

<logic equal=developer>
TheButton
</logic equal>

<logic NotEqual=developer>
TheButton=disabled
</logic NotEqual>
```

So here code keeps increasing and access control is all fragmented.

In struts2, for each method inside Action class, I can create Custom Annotation and check access control. Like `@Role=pm,developer`

How to do it in jsp ? such that i can write.

```
<button name=Thebutton access="pm,developer" >
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a method in your controller saying "getElements()" which would return back only permitted elements. Feel free to even write simpler actions returning back individual elements or blank string so that your main.jsp remains clean.

Comment: Can u elaborate a bit in details. Basically, say i want to make one button visible for access=x

Comment: I think you want to render a disabled button too. Apologies for my earlier answer. In this case you could simply create a button.tag file where you could add this iffy logic. Add one action in your controller isEnabled(button) and that method would check on all your permissions and give a boolean value based on which you would display enabled or disabled button. Does that help?